# Сортировка цвета

Tags: ruby

У меня такой вопрос, есть ли возможность, как-то отсортровать цвета по оттенкам?

```
My_hash = {"1"=>["#00050c"], 
 "2"=>["#ffffff"], 
 "3"=>["#d6e7ff"],
 "4"=>["#008000"],
 "5"=>["#0768ef"],
 "6"=>["#07408e"],
 "7"=>["#42AAFF"],
 "8"=>["#21406b"],
 "9"=>["#032656"]}
My_hash.each_value {|value| puts value}
```

Comment: По оттенку это-о... по H (hue) из HSL?

Comment: Да, именно так.

Comment: вот что-то похожее https://github.com/melborne/colorable

Comment: Собственно, да. `sort_by`+вычисление оттенка из цветостроки библиотекой выше или иным способом.